# How can I mix colors?

Tags: color

As far as I know if you combine  `Blue` and `Green`  the result is `Cyan` (using additive mixing). I would like to know some basic arithmetic of colors for making a *Mathematica* game for kids (using colored numbers).

**My problem is** what is the result of mixing $2\times Blue + 1\times Cyan$?

Or consider a more complicated example: $3\times Red + 2\times Green + 2\times Blue$.

Is this color arithmetic the same for subtractive and additive mixing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`RGBColor[{red channel, green channel, blue channel}]` defines a color. Here is a didactic example of this:

```
mix[r_, g_, b_] := If[Max[{r, g, b}] > 0, RGBColor[{r, g, b}/Max[{r, g, b}]], RGBColor[{0, 0, 0}]]
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   mix[r, g, b],
   Rectangle[]
   }],
 {r, 0, 100, 1}, {g, 0, 100, 1}, {b, 0, 100, 1}
 ]
```

`{r,g,b}` has been normalized so that the largest component is 1, because values larger than 1 are clipped by *Mathematica*.

For your complicated example, you simply have to write `RGBColor[{3,2,5}/5]`.

Try typing `Cyan` into *Mathematica*. It will return `RGBColor[0, 1, 1]`. So the result of mixing 2 X blue plus 1 X cyan is `RGBColor[(2 {0, 0, 1} + {0, 1, 1})/3]`.

*Mathematica* helps you mix colors with the function `Blend`. For example `Blend[{Blue, Cyan}, 1/3]` returns `RGBColor[0, 1/3, 1]` which is exactly what the computation above returns.

There is also `CMYKColor` which works the same way, but instead of specifying red, green and blue components we specify cyan, magenta, yellow and black.

Comment: And to answer the second part of the OP's question, this is additive mixing.

Comment: Your `mix` can be written shorter with `RGBColor @@ Normalize[{r,g,b}, Max]` :)

Comment: @Kuba Nice, I didn't know about the second argument.